# Copying file between machines without uploading my private key

Tags: linux, ssh, file-copy

I have SSH access to two machines which I want to copy a big file between them. I also have `sudo` privileges, but I do not wish in any way to upload my private key file to one of the machines to login from number 1 to number 2.
What do you think?

Comment: Have you looked into ssh agent forwarding?

Comment: `What do you think?` .. i think that apples are delicious ... please ask a specific question about the problem

Answer (score 1):

" ... I do not wish in any way to upload **my** private key file to one of the machines ... "

It seems your main concern is about "*your own*" private key leaving your machine - but you don't need to give "*your own*" private key.

On your "desktop/administration" machine, just generate "one-time" new key pair (with ssh-keygen), naming it differently than the default, say, *onetimekey*. Protect your the newly created private key with long passphrase.
Upload the new (freshly created) private key *onetimekey* to, say server1, other key, i.e new public key *onetimekey.pub* upload to server2.
From server1, using freshly created private key, scp your file/s to server2.
Or generate new key pair directly on server1, download the new public key to your administration machine, from there upload it to the server2.

Of course after uploading your public key to the server2 you need to "put" it at right location (default ~/.ssh/authorized_keys).

In short (while you are at your 'desktop/administration' machine):

```
ssh-keygen
# on the first prompt give 'onetimekey' name for the new key pair
# on 'passphrase' prompt give very long passphrase to secure your private key
scp onetimekey user1@server1:/home/user1/.ssh
scp onetimekey.pub user2@server2:/home/user2
ssh user2@server2 "cat onetimekey.pub >> .ssh/authorized_keys" # note >>, do not use >, > overwrites files
ssh user1@server1 # you are at server1 now, and from server1 run command below:
scp -i .ssh/onetimekey your_big_file user2@server2:/home/user2
```

Sorry if I'm wrong about "my private key concern" - I hope I didn't miss the whole thing :).

Edit (due to OP comment below):
OP asked if he can use/create temp users on server1 and server2 machines.
Of course, you can do it if you want that route:

```
sudo useradd user1 # on server1 machine
sudo useradd user2 # on server2 machine
# do your work
sudo userdel -r user1 # on server1; -r for deleting home directory, i.e., /home/user1
sudo userdel -r user2 # on server2
```

You can create the user with the same name on those servers, say user1 on both, server1 and server2 (in that case change the code above).

Important part of my comment about using temp users:
when I said in my comment "*After you finished your work just delete everything (private/**public** keys...*"
If someone misunderstand authorized_keys, he/she can think the authorized_keys file is a public key. The authorized_keys file is not public key, it contains public key/s, so do not delete authorized_keys file in your .ssh directory (you will lock yourself once you leave ongoing ssh session).
However, if you will use temp users then, even if you delete authorized_keys file (/home/temp_user/.ssh/authorized_keys) it will not be the problem for you.

Comment: Thanks. Looks great. Can I also make just a temp user on machine1 and machine2?

Comment: Of course. After you finished your work you just delete everything (private/public keys, temp users user1/user2). If you will not create temp users, you don't event need sudo at all... But if you want that route (using temp users):

Comment: @Stat.Enthus, I'm struggling with formating my comment...        
            
      `sudo useradd user1 # on server1`      
      `sudo useradd user2 # on server2`      
      `#after you finished your work`      
      `sudo userdel -r user1 # on server1; -r to remove home directory, i.e., /home/user1`      
      `sudo userdel -r user2 # on server2`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could pull it off using 2 tunnels and then using `nc`. Say we want to move a file from `box1` to `box2`.

```
ssh -L 4444:localhost:4444 user@box2 # open my box' port 4444 and connect to port 4444 on box2
ssh -R 4444:localhost:4444 user@box1 # open box1's port 4444 and connect to port 4444 on my box
```

Now, whatever you connect to box1 port 4444 will try to use port 4444 on box2

On box2:

```
nc -l 4444 > the_file
```

On box1:

```
nc localhost 4444 < the_file
```

Would love to hear about other techniques, just in case.

Comment: Its a pretty big file (50 GB). Do you think netcat will be able to handle that?

Comment: I don't see any reason why it would fail... might as well try piecing it with `split` and sending each part separately.

Comment: This would transfer the data over the users network connection rather than between remote machines directly.

Comment: The comment by @Hermann is correct. If you're going to go that route you might as well use `scp -3` to transfer the files.

Comment: `scp -3` Oh, this is so cool. Do you mind providing that as an answer? I will upvote it right away. It is a lot less hassle than what I provided.